How to put a ggplot into a Word doc using Officer in R?
I am attempting to use bookmarks in Word to automatically place plots into a report.
I have already used "body_replace_flextable_at_bkm" to add flextables automatically, however I cannot find a function to do so for plots. I saw "replace_external_img" but not plot!
Here is what I tried, but obviously it did not work because the plots are not external images:
template <- read_docx("C:/Users/Documents/template.docx")
body_replace_img_at_bkm(template,"plot1",plot1) # bookmark is named plot1, as well as the R plot 
print(template,target="C:/Users/Documents/template.docx")

Output: Error in body_replace_img_at_bkm(template, "plot1", plot1) :
inherits(value, "external_img") is not TRUE

While the flextable package provides a convenience function to replace a bookmark with a flextable object, the officer only provides functions to replace a bookmark with text or an image.
But one option to achieve your desired result would be to save your plot to a temporary file and then replace the bookmark with the image file using body_replace_img_at_bkm.
UPDATE
After a look at how body_replace_flextable_at_bkm is implemented, a shorter approach would be to use cursor_bookmark and body_add_gg where for the latter we have to use pos = "on" to replace the bkm with the plot:
template <- read_docx()
template <- body_add_par(template, "[Insert plot here]")
template <- body_bookmark(template, "plot1")
template <- body_add_par(template, "Bla Bla Bla")
template <- cursor_bookmark(template, "plot1")
template <- body_add_gg(
  x = template, value = plot1, width = 16 / 2.54, height = 9 / 2.54,
  pos = "on"
)
print(template, target = "template1.docx")

And similar to the edit by @Axeman we can wrap this in a function:
body_replace_gg_at_bkm <- function(x,
                                   bookmark,
                                   value,
                                   width = 6,
                                   height = 5,
                                   res = 300,
                                   style = "Normal",
                                   scale = 1,
                                   ...) {
  x <- cursor_bookmark(x, bookmark)
  x <- body_add_gg(
    x = x, value = value, width = width, height = height,
    res = res, style = style, scale = scale, pos = "on", ...
  )
  x
}

Original Post
Using a minimal reproducible example based on the default docx template shipped with officer:
library(ggplot2)
library(officer)

plot1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point()

template <- read_docx()
template <- body_add_par(template, "[Insert plot here]")
template <- body_bookmark(template, "plot1")

template <- body_replace_img_at_bkm(
  template, "plot1",
  external_img(
    src = ggsave(
      tempfile(fileext = ".png"), plot1,
      width = 16,
      height = 9,
      unit = "cm"
    ),
    width = 16,
    height = 9,
    unit = "cm"
  )
) # bookmark is named plot1, as well as the R plot
print(template, target = "template.docx")


If you do this sort of thing more often, you can define a simple function to do this for you, e.g.:
body_replace_img_with_plot_at_bkm <- function(
    x, bookmark, plot, width = 16, height = 9 # in cm
) {
  body_replace_img_at_bkm(
    x, bookmark,
    external_img(
      src = ggsave(
        tempfile(fileext = ".png"), plot,
        width = width,
        height = height,
        unit = "cm"
      ),
      width = width,
      height = height,
      unit = "cm"
    )
  )
}

Then use as:
template <- body_replace_img_with_plot_at_bkm(template, "plot1", plot1)


Thx @Axeman for the edit. Was my thought too and I think that might be a nice feature to add to the officer package.

Thank you, I will try this tomorrow! I believe I actually resorted to using something similar to this method, but I was getting an error: Error in docxpart_replace_img_at_bkm(node = x$doc_obj$get(), bookmark = bookmark,  :
could not find any bookmark plot1 located INSIDE a single paragraph -- despite there 100% being an existing bookmark called plot1. Could this have to do with the way my template doc is formatted? (as in, its paragraphs)

I just added an Update which IMHO is easier. Concerning your issue: In general I don't think that the formatting of your template is the issue. The first guess would be that there is no bookmark. But as you are sure that there is a bookmark ... Second thought: In your code you are overwriting the template.docx. Could this be an issue? Perhaps you have replaced (aka removed) the bkm by accident? If that is not the case then I'm afraid one needs your template.docx file to reproduce your issue and check out a solution.

Perfect. I grabbed the body_add_gg portion and ran it, and for whatever reason that was able to identify the bookmark that body_replace_img_at_bkm could not. Hopefully this helps anyone else who has this issue...I agree with you both that adding a body_replace_gg/plot_at_bkm would be a great addition to the package.
